# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NonExistentDocumentException'

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-authentication, swift4

The application crashed when I run it.

The debug console result:

> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> `<NSLayoutConstraint:0x108597170 UIView:0x10857e6e0.trailingMargin == UIButton:0x10b50fa60'Filters'.trailing + 8 (active)>`

> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
>   The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.

> 2018-10-09 11:13:05.328331+0800 KAppLocator[438:86468] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
>   2018-10-09 11:13:05.349980+0800 KAppLocator[438:86468] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
>   2018-10-09 11:13:07.929435+0800 KAppLocator[438:86324] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NonExistentDocumentException', reason: 'Document '' doesn't exist. Check document.exists to make sure the document exists before calling document.data.'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x18101ed8c 0x1801d85ec 0x100b916e8 0x100a3c460 0x100a3df74 0x100a3e01c 0x100b909dc 0x100b90ff4 0x1035f91dc 0x1035f919c 0x1035fdd2c 0x180fc7070 0x180fc4bc8 0x180ee4da8 0x182eca020 0x18af04758 0x100ad8324 0x180975fc0)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

I've check the FSTDocumentsKey and the users/zdfWJ3sv2JXgYu8iXsA0tGI1CYF2> and the documents key exists in firebase.

Found out also the error, Thread 1 signal SIGBART [FIRDocumentSnapshot data]

What is the possible cause of crashing?

Thank you in advance, folks! :)

Comment: please share your code snippet where are you getting exception?

Comment: and try with this one please `if let document = document, document.exists {
        print(document.data())
    }`

Comment: What you configured from Firebase....

Comment: See this function(First function) @IBAction func doReadDeepDocument(_ sender: Any) { in this link https://frageit.de/questions/49087982/firestore-getdocument-crashes-app-if-document-does-not-exist

Comment: let ref: DocumentReference = self.db.collection(KDB.Table.users).document(uid)
        ref.getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document {
                for docu in document.data() {
                    SpeedLog.print("SearchViewController docu.key:\(docu.key)")

Comment: This part getting exception, for docu in document.data() {

Comment: Still not running.

Comment: How about the possible cause is pods? Do I need to re-download and re-install all pods?

Comment: It's great that you've included the error in your question but we need to see the *code* that caused the error. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This issue has been solved. Just missing data users in firebase. Thank you, everyone :)